# Application of Continuous Mapping theorem to logarithm of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence

In the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem) of Continuous Mapping Theorem, it reads if $g$ is any function between two metric spaces and $X_n$ converges in law to $X$ which almost surely will not take value in the discontinuity set $D_g$ of $g$, then $g(X_n)$ converges in law to $g(X)$.

So suppose I have some random variables $X_n\in\mathbb{C}$ converges in law to some $X\in\mathbb{C}$, such that $P(X=0)=0$, then I should have $\log(X_n)$ converges in law to $\log(X)$, am I correct?

Comment: I think you might have to be a bit careful with how you define the complex logarithm here

Comment: Correct, if $X_n$'s are positive.

Comment: @Lorago: May I ask why is that? Say if I just take the principal branch, will it work?